# Does RxJava2 auto dispose observable when they call completed or error?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a question about the disposal on RxJava. I found this below sentence on RxSwift document on Github.

> When a sequence sends the `completed` or `error` event all internal resources that compute sequence elements will be freed.
>
> To cancel production of sequence elements and free resources immediately, call dispose on the returned subscription.

if I understand correctly the resources (observables) will be freed after they call `onCompleted` or `onError`.

So the question is, does RxJava do the same thing like RxSwift or I need to call the dispose by myself?

Answer (score 21):

Yes, all associated resources will be disposed automatically. To illustrate run following test with RxJava 2:

```
boolean isDisposed = false;

@Test 
public void testDisposed(){
    TestObserver<Integer> to = Observable.<Integer>create(subscriber -> {
        subscriber.setDisposable(new Disposable() {

            @Override
            public boolean isDisposed() {
                return isDisposed;
            }

            @Override
            public void dispose() {
                isDisposed = true;
            }
        });
        subscriber.onComplete();
    }).test();

    to.assertComplete();
    assertTrue(isDisposed);
}
```

Comment: I'm sure I read somewhere that `.isDisposed()` is not guaranteed to return `true` unless the `.dispose()` method has been explicitly called. IOW an `Observable` can complete and still return `false` for `.isDisposed()`.

Comment: if it disposed automatically why doOnDispose() not called?

Comment: Agreed with @RobertLewis I don't think this is guaranteed. Read more : https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5283

Comment: @PavelPoley You can find the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49154248/1000551