# Why is doOnDispose not called?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-java3

When creating an Observable like this:

```
public void foo() {

    Observable observable = Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
        bar();
        return "";
      })
      .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> System.out.println("onSubscribe"))
      .doOnDispose(() -> System.out.println("onDispose"));

    Disposable disposable = observable.subscribe();
    disposable.dispose();    
}

private void bar() {
    System.out.println("bar");
}
```

`doOnSubcribe` is called, `doOnDispose` is not called.

Why is that?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to use the `doFinally()` operator.

`doOnDispose()` has a very narrow use case, where the observable is explicitly disposed. In your example, the observable terminates "naturally" by `onComplete()`. By the time that you call `dispose()`, the observable is done, and nothing will happen -- disposing a completed observable has no effect.