# RxJava disposing Observable/Flowable in a microservice Server project

Tags: server, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-java3

I am using RxJava for a server microservice project, where using Jetty as HTTP Servlet server.

I am handling requests either from client or main server with Observable for different flows.
When a request hitting the api below, I will return a Response after Observable finishes the job.

```
@GET
@Path("{uuid}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response doThingsForClient(@PathParam("uuid") String uuid) {
   Worker worker = new Worker(uuid);
   worker.run();
   return Response.ok("Awesome").build();
}

class Worker {
   String uuid = null;
   public Worker(String uuid) {
      this.uuid = uuid;
   }

   public void run() {
      Observable.concat(Observable1,Observable2,Observable3);
   }
}
```

I am wondering if I need to dispose these Observables or Flowables.
According to this: [Does RxJava2 auto dispose observable when they call completed or error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45589930/does-rxjava2-auto-dispose-observable-when-they-call-completed-or-error) 
and the RxJava3 sourcecode, i don't think Flowable at least is disposed automatically?

If I need to manually dispose the resources,
Is it better to create a `CompositeDisposable`, then add disposable to the `CompositeDisposable` at each Observer(`Observable1...Observable3`)'s `onSubscribe()` being called, call `compositeDisposable.dispose()` after the `concat` finishes.

Should I also monitor the Jetty `AbstractLifeCycle` to dispose these Observables(It sounds similar as Android)? I am not sure how other people are using RxJava at the server side, open to any suggestions to these questions and general Rx approach at server projects.

Thanks!

Comment: It's tough to tell from the question since we don't see what the observers are doing. Generally speaking, I don't believe you have to dispose manually if the observables are completing.

Comment: yeah, onComplete should dispose the resources.